# How to make infinite sequence of 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sequence

`Sequence :: [Integer]`

I thought I should first make sequence `[1,2,3,...]` and iterate each item to make a sequence of  `1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ...`.

How to put this in a Haskell way of code?

Comment: what did you try? What is not working?

Comment: No problem, it's a simple composition of basic enumeration primitives, `join ((((>>=) . enumFrom) <*>) . flip . (enumFromThenTo <*>) . subtract) 1`. What could be easier? Nah, nah, I'm just kidding. If you want a solution that looks like something you might have written yourself, you gotta show us what you can write yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Basically here you have subsequences which each time decrement to `1`, so:

```
[1]
[2, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
⋮
```

We can thus work with list comprehension and define this as:

```
[x | b <- [1 ..], x <- …]
```

where I leave filling in `…` as an exercise. It should construct a list that starts at `b` and ends with `1`, so `b`, `b-1`, `b-2`, etc.

For the first 20 items, we then get:

```
[1,2,1,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2]
```

or with a monadic function:

```
[1 ..] >>= \b -> …
```

which produces the same values:

```
[1,2,1,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2]
```

Comment: Could you please give me more hint? Sorry I'm totally beginner to Haskell :(

Comment: @proceeder: try working with a range like `[x, y, .. 1]` where you need to fill in `x` and `y` as expressions with `b` as variable.

Comment: Variable not in scope: (...) :: Integer -> t0 -> Integer
    |
Sequence = [x | b <- [1 ..], x <- [b, b-1 ... 1 ]]

Comment: I get this error...

Comment: @proceeder: you used three dots, but it should be two dots, so `[b, b-1 .. 1]`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to do it:

```
sequence = concatMap (\n -> [n, n-1 .. 1]) [1..]
```

(note that you can't call it `Sequence`, as names with an uppercase first letter are reserved for either types or data constructors, not normal values)

I hope this is simple enough to understand. What we do is:

1. take the infinite list of integers `[1..]`
2. apply to each integer the function `\n -> [n, n-1 .. 1]` - this is the function which takes eg `2` to `[2,1]`, `5` to `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` and so on
3. use `concatMap` to apply this function to each element of the list but flatten the resulting list of lists into one. Had you used `map` instead of `concatMap`, the result would be `[[1], [2, 1], [3, 2, 1], ...]` - using `concatMap` instead is what removes the inner lists.

Comment: I wondered why you did `\n -> [n, n-1 ... 1]` rather than just `\n -> [n .. 1]`.  I tried it, and it never terminated.  Reading through [Learn You a Haskell's section on ranges](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#texas-ranges), I learned that you need to specify a step (the value after the comma) if you want it to be something other than '1'. (Here, we want it to be '-1'.)

Comment: That's indeed true. Well done for working it out, and apologies I didn't think to mention it!

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Start with what you have:

```
xs1 = [1]
```

But that's not the while story of course. You have

```
xs2 = [1] ++ [2,1]
```

but actually

```
xs4 = [1] ++ [2,1] ++ [3,2,1] ++ [4,3,2,1]
```

If you now give this to somebody and they check it with e.g. `take 7` they won't even see the difference! But of course we want to generalize it, so that `take n` for any `n` will see the correct sequence.

So then, what if we write it as

```
ys4 = [ [i,i-1 .. 1] | i <- [1,2,3,4] ]
    = [ [i,i-1 .. 1] | i <- [1..4]    ]
    = [ [1]  , [2,1] ,  [3,2,1] ,  [4,3,2,1] ]
 -- /=  [1] ++ [2,1] ++ [3,2,1] ++ [4,3,2,1]   == xs4
 --      1   ,  2,1  ,   3,2,1  ,   4,3,2,1 ,  ... 5,4,3,2,1, ...?
 -- i =  1   ,  2    ,   3      ,   4       ,  ... 5,         ...?
```

? Seems to be doing what you wanted to do, starting from the sequence of `i`s, the `1, 2, 3, 4,...`

It's not *the same* as `xs4`, but it follows it closely. We just need to *concatenate* these lists together, to turn those commas into the `++`s, to get the `xs4` back.

There's a common built-in function already that does that. You can find it e.g. by hoogling for its type, [`[[a]] -> [a]`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D&scope=set%3Astackage).

And why should we limit ourselves to just `4`? Let's make it a parameter:

```
ysn n = theFunction [ [i,i-1 .. 1] | i <- [1..n] ]
```

so it works for any `n` we'd specify.

But do we really need to be specifying that `n`?